# Programatically Hide/Show Android Soft Keyboard not Working Api 16 working in gretherthen 16

Tags: android

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.showSoftInput(Search_client,
                        InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard

Answer (score 0):

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
```

to show keyboard

```
public void ShowKeyboard(View view){
 imm.showSoftInput(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
}
```

to hide keyboard

```
public void HideKeyboard(View view){
     imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
    }
```